# Fetch data json in react-native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I want to ask
I was able to display Api data using the Fetch method, before I displayed the data using Flatlist and it worked. then I customize the display using the timeline, when I render the data into the view, why doesn't it appear?

my code

```
 constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
          data: [],
          isLoading : true
      }
  }
    fetchData = async() =>{
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const response =  await fetch('https://example.com/get_by?id_order='+ params.id);
        const json = await response.json(); // products have array data
        this.setState({data: json.data}); // filled data with dynamic array
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
  };

  renderDetail() {
    let title = <Text style={[styles.title]}>{this.state.item.awb}</Text>
    var desc = null
    if(this.state.description)
      desc = (
        <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>   
           <Text style={[styles.textDescription]}>{this.state.description}</Text>
        </View>
      )

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {title}
        {desc}
      </View>
    )
  }

  renderDetail() {
    let title = <Text style={[styles.title]}>{this.state.item.awb}</Text>
    var desc = null
    if(this.state.status)
      desc = (
        <View style={styles.list}>   
           <Text style={[styles.list]}>{this.state.status}</Text>
        </View>
      )

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {title}
        {desc}
      </View>
    )
  }

    render(){
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        const {timeline} = this.state;

       return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.pageName}>{params.id}</Text>
         <Timeline renderDetail={this.renderDetail}

            circleSize={20}
            separator={true}
            circleColor='blue'
            lineColor='gray'
            timeStyle={styles.time}
            descriptionStyle={styles.description}
            style={styles.list}
            data={this.state.data}
          />
       </View>
       );
   }
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
I tried like this, but still can't

Comment: let us see how you're importing Timeline

Comment: import Timeline from 'react-native-timeline-flatlist';

Comment: as you can see in the [Documentation](https://github.com/eugnis/react-native-timeline-flatlist#configuration) `renderItem` is not a valid prop

Comment: can give an example sir? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add  `data={this.state.data}` to your `Timeline` component. It will sort look like this:

```
<Timeline data={this.state.data}  ...otherprops />
```

*Update :*

```
const mappedData = this.state.data.map((item => {
 return {
   time:item.date,
   title:item.awb,
   description:item.status
 }
}))

<Timeline data={mappedData}  ...other props />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212130/discussion-on-answer-by-ajin-kabeer-fetch-data-json-in-react-native).